# OpenCV: In which version the feature2d module was first implemented?

Tags: opencv

In need to in which version the `feature2d` module was first implemented. Couldn't find an answer on google. I know that it exists in `2.2`, but I wanted to know if it existed already on `2.0` or `2.1`.

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to know this?

Comment: I'm writing the documentation to an algorithm I'm adding the feature2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenCV's ChangeLog](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#22), it is first introduced in `v2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 2.2 is the first version with modules, including features2d. You can verify this yourself by examining the [source code releases](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).